# Using a variable to select how many cells get added together

Tags: excel-formula

I am having trouble figuring out what should be a relatively simple excel task.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a list of years with specific values tied to each year.

End Goal: Make a drop-down box with years, when a year is selected all of the values tied to the years will be summed up and a total will be displayed.  For example here is my list for columns A and B:

- 2015, 10
- 2016, 20
- 2017, 5

When my drop-down selects 2015, it would return a value of "10". 
When my drop-down selects 2016, it would return a value of "30".
When my drop-down selects 2017, it would return a value of "35".

I had no problem creating the drop down.

Next I created a cell that subtracts 2015 (and adds one) from whatever value is selected in the drop-down. (e.g. if they select 2016, it returns a value of "2").   I then defined this cell as the variable "Year_Span".

So my thought was to somehow create a function that basically does =SUM(B1:B(Year_Span)).  That is, my values that I want to sum are on the "B" row, and I want to sum between "B1" and "BX", X being whatever value was returned form Year_Span.

So that's what I'm trying to do, if there is a better way to go about doing it, I'm all ears!

Thank you for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `INDIRECT` and `MATCH` to accomplish this. The examples below assume the drop-down list is E1; change if needed.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B1:B"&MATCH($E$1,$A:$A,0)))
```

However, this formula will be based on the order of your data. If you want it to always add from the lowest year to the selected year, regardless of row order, you could use SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF($A:$A,"<="&$E$1,$B:$B)
```

Let me know if either of these work for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic range reference using `INDEX` to get the upper end of a range.  Note that using `INDEX` is non-volitile (unlike `INDIRECT`)

If the Dropdown value (year) is in cell `C1`, formula is

```
=SUM($B$1:INDEX($A:$B,MATCH($C$1,$A:$A,0),2))
```